# jQuery - livequery plugin help

Tags: jquery, livequery

I add update messages as table rows when a user changes a radio button. I was running into the fact that once the message was added it didn't have the functionality that I thought it would since it was added after the page was already loaded. Then I found the livequery plugin that seemed to allow elements added after the fact to have the same functionality as elements loaded with the page.

I have the click fadeout() working correctly, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for setTimeout() on the table row that was just added. I know the current syntax is NOT correct, and I left it at the point where I was frustrated.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input[@name='optInOut']").change(function(){
        $('#tblUpdates').append('<tr class="msgUpdate"><td colspan="2">added message0</td><td align="right"><img src="../Images/CCC/12-em-cross.png" class="imgClose" alt="close message" title="close message" /></td></tr>');
    });

    setTimeout($.livequery.function() {  
        $('.msgUpdate').fadeOut('normal');  
        }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    });

    $('img.imgClose').livequery('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('normal');
  }); 
</script>
```

If I need to provide more information I will attempt to do so and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I may remove the setTimeout() section all together. I'll let the user close the message on their own. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all this bit here

```
     $('img.imgClose').livequery('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('normal');
}); 
</script>
```

should be

```
     $('img.imgClose').livequery('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('normal');
     });//<--- closes the livequery call
});//<--- closes document.ready
</script>
```

secondly, i recommend against livequery for the fadeOut, but if you are going to use it, this syntax:

```
setTimeout($.livequery.function() {  
        $('.msgUpdate').fadeOut('normal');  
        }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    });
```

should be:

```
$.livequery(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('.msgUpdate').fadeOut('normal'); 
  },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to call window.setTimeout? I'm not sure if that is necessary, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

With the newest edition of jQuery (1.3.X) you do not need to use the livequery plugin.  You can just use $("div").live("click",etc....

I think if you look at the new live function of jQuery you might be able to clean up you Javascript so that it is more understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure if the current 1.3.x version of jQuery would cause any problems with the code we are currently using. We are on 1.2.6, since that is what was out when the site was originally developed.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal with the setTimeout is to fade elements that existed when the page was loaded, then you shouldn't need to involve livequery

```
setTimeout("$('.msgUpdate').fadeOut('normal');", 1000);
```